# How to make a Django view ONLY accessible to Unauthenticated users?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm building a Django API view by extending the `rest_framework.views.APIView` class.

I have successfully built many APIs that are only callable by an authenticated user. I have done this by adding: `permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]`

There are some APIs that I only want unauthenticated users to call. Such as "ForgotPassword". Basically, I want  to ensure that the  API caller doesn't send in the JWT Token in the request header. How can I enforce that? There is no `permissions.IsUnAuthenticated`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can easily create your own `IsNotAuthenticated` class

something like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsNotAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to non authenticated users.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return not request.user.is_authenticated()
```

then: `permission_classes = (myapp.permissions.IsNotAuthenticated,)`

regards.

Comment: would you remove () from is_authenticated() it's not required. If you dont it. Your answer is wrong base on the django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using function based view then it would be good if you use the following.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
@user_passes_test(lambda u: not u.is_authenticated())
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in permissions.py like this (For who were getting bool object error)

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsNotAuthenticated(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return not request.user.is_authenticated
```

And in the main view

```
 from .permissions import IsNotAuthenticated
 
 permission_classes = [IsNotAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is for *Django* not *Django REST Framework*

For a Class-Based View, make a custom mixin like this

```
class IsNotAuthenticatedMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    """
    Allows access only to non authenticated users.
    """

    def test_func(self):
        return not self.request.user.is_authenticated

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('home')
```

You can inherit any Class based view from `IsNotAuthenticatedMixin`